# How to stop or cancel Mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener form executing Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
MediaPlayer player;

protected void playaudio() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            System.out.println("setOnPreparedListener executed");
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    try {
        player.setDataSource(mContext,
                Uri.parse("http://radio-electron.ru:8000/96"));
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
}
public void stopaudio() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

Even if i call `stopaudio()` method, the code inside `setOnPreparedListener` is executed. How can i stop or cancel the setOnPreparedListener from execution when i stop the `player`. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

you can reset the listener instance, passing null as parameter. E.g.

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(null);
```

on `stopaudio()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
```

You can use above code before the declaration of player = new MediaPlayer();
Like:-

```
MediaPlayer player;

protected void playaudio() {
 if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            System.out.println("setOnPreparedListener executed");
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    try {
        player.setDataSource(mContext,
                Uri.parse("http://radio-electron.ru:8000/96"));
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
}
public void stopaudio() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

I hope it works for you.